# copy values from select input to text input with X amount of select and input fields

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have this Javascript code that copies select options values into a text input:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#category2 option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == $("#category").val();
    }).attr('selected', true);
    $("#category2").live("change", function() {
        $("#category").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    });
    });
</script>
```

how can i do this with a dynamic amount of text fields

i am selecting data from a MySQL database in PHP and showing it in a while loop...

```
$sql="SELECT * from website_sliderimages ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    echo '<form method="post" action="editsliderimage.php" id="editsliderimage">
    <select name="select1">
    ... options ...
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="input1" />
    </form>';
}
```

how can i change it to do this? at the moment the above code will only do one select area and text input

Answer (score 0):

On your server-side html, put a class on your drop down.

`<select class="mydropdown">
...
</select>`

Then, on the client side, bind an event to all elements on the page that match the selector:

`$('body').on('change', '.mydropdown', function() {
    // do whatever you need to do here.
}`

Fyi, the [on() function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is a replacement for live() which is now deprecated. Also, I would recommend you not use echo for your html code. It would be way easier for you to do this:

```
while (condition)
{ ?>

<span>You can just write HTML here...</span>

<?php }
```

That way, you don't have to worry about escape characters.